# Perform element-wise subtract from the vector

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate the sum of elementwise subtracts from the vector from the following equitation:

```
sum(y(i) - y(j)) at i!=j
```

y is given as a numpy array 
One option is to iterate through the double loop:

```
dev = 0

for i in range(y.shape[0]):
   for j in range(y.shape[0]):
      if i == j:
         continue
      dev += y[i, j] - y[i, j]
```

That is definitely not the optimal solution. 
How it can be optimized using vectorized operations with numpy vectors?

Comment: `y[i, j] - y[i, j]` will always be `0`... or `nan`. What do you want exactly ? A kind of cartesian substraction ? Has `y` vocation to be large ? Otherwise, something you could do is `np.abs(y[:, None] - y[None, :]).sum()/2`.

Comment: This can be a nice [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Say `y` is flat, e.g.

```
>>> y = np.arange(10)
>>> y
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> y.shape
(10,)
```

You could compute the "cartesian differences" as follows

```
>>> m = np.abs(y[:, None] - y[None, :])
>>> m
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

and finally

```
>>> dev = m.sum()/2
>>> dev
165.0
```

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools` `combination`:

```
import itertools
sum([x2 - x1 for x1, x2 in itertools.combinations(y, 2)])
```

using `np.subtract.outer`

```
np.abs(np.subtract.outer(y,y)).sum()/2
```

---

### Time Comparison:

**Method 1 (Using Itertools):**

> Wall time: 18.9 s

**Method 2 (Using KeepAlive's cartesian differences):**

> Wall time: 491 ms

**Method 3 (Using np.subtract.outer):**

> Wall time: 467 ms

Comment: Your performance results clearly depend on the examples of `y` you take, i.e. of their `~.size`. May be good to explicite that. Putting aside the `itertools` case, I otherwise do not really see the point with such comparison, quasi fallacious.

Comment: @keepAlive: yeah I took 10K points. Yeah last two are almost same.

Comment: I guess that with, say , 5000 points, the naive approach is faster ? Why not show it ? hum...

Comment: @keepAlive: How naive approach will be faster? Let me add for the naive solution also.

Comment: You have changed your answer since then ;) (not the computing times though ??) Before that you had the extra cost of triangle indexing. Henceforth, your answer is indeed probably faster for all size since you do not have the vertical/horizontal reshaping cost that my approach entails.

Comment: @keepAlive: Yes, I also updated the time computation l. The last two method have not so significant difference :p. Earlier ur was faster because I used indexing thing. But then I realised there is something wrong. Yours and `np.subtract.outer` are similar :D so I updated the answer in that way. :)